# Cannot export Influxdb into CSV file

Tags: csv, command-prompt, export-to-csv, influxdb

So basically i want to export a database from influxdb to csv format in command line.

I type this command in the command line:

```
influx -database 'RoadMonitoringDB' -execute 'select * from vehicle' -format 'csv' > test.csv
```

It supposed to correctly export it into csv file, but what i get now is this:

> unknown arguments: * from vehicle' -format 'csv'

What went wrong here? Because when i type `influx -help`, the command should be like this:

> influx -database 'metrics' -execute 'select * from cpu' -format 'json' -pretty

Any answers is really helpful. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version are you using?
I just checked it on 1.7.6 and it works fine:

```
[root@mon-01 ~]# influx -version
InfluxDB shell version: 1.7.6
Enter an InfluxQL query
[root@mon-01 ~]# influx -precision 'rfc3339' -database 'myMetrics' -execute 'select * from up' -format 'csv' >up.txt
```

BTW - the `-precision 'rfc3339'` is just for getting a readable timestamp.

Comment: my influx is actually version 1.7.5, and yup. it's not working, even though i put .txt in the file name

Comment: Please notice that 1.7.5 is a problematic version. You should upgrade to 1.7.6 or downgrade. Make sure to read the release notes https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/about_the_project/releasenotes-changelog/

Answer (score 0):

I compared to how I do it, and the only difference I found was:

You are writing:

```
-format 'csv' > test.csv
```

I write it as:

```
-format csv > test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote from CSV, it works

```
$ influx -database 'RoadMonitoringDB' -execute 'select * from vehicle' -format 'csv' > test.csv
```

But in the result, the timestamp will look like this:

```
1204554500000000000
```

So to get the timestamp in RFC3339 formats, like this:

```
2021-06-06T00:00:00
```

```
$ influx -precision 'rfc3339' -database 'RoadMonitoringDB' -execute 'select * from vehicle' -format 'csv' > test.csv
```